# text file string split then output each element into view table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a text file containing a paygroup and a creation date separated by pipeline as the example below

> PG1|3/21/2019
>   PG2|3/21/2019
>   PG3|3/21/2019

I am trying to split the string so that I can output something like this but with the date split and placed under Date added.

[image: Table]

However when I pull the data it goes under one column. How can I loop the date in from the list in order to be displayed next to the proper paygroup? I currently have it split as it's read into an array, and then placed in a list. I'm not sure if there's a better more optimal way?

```
View

@model WebApplication2.Models.UploadFiles

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Paygroup Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Update Paygroup</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "UpdateFiles", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PayGroup, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PayGroup, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.PayGroup) } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PayGroup, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" />
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Paygroups</th>
        <th>Date added</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var pg in Model.Paygroups)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@pg</td>
        </tr>

    }
    @foreach (var date in Model.DateAdded)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@date</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Controller

```
public class UpdateFilesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Default
        public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            var fullpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/sourcefiles"), "paygroup.txt");
            List<string> paygroupsList = new List<string>();
            List<string> DateList = new List<string>();
            string line;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(fullpath))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] strArray = line.Split('|');
                    paygroupsList.Add(strArray[0]);
                    DateList.Add(strArray[1]);
                }
                UploadFiles model = new UploadFiles()
                {
                    Paygroups = paygroupsList,
                    DateAdded = DateList
                };
                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

Model

```
public class UploadFiles
{
    public List<string> Paygroups { get; set; }
    public List<string> DateAdded { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a paygroup.")]
    [Remote("DoesPaygroupExist", "UpdateFiles", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Paygroup already exists!")]
    public string PayGroup { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: The way you have your code your loosing any association between the pay group and date added.  It looks like that is a core design issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you actually ask the view to loop for each column separately. and your model is not designed properly.

Model should be something like this instead:

```
public class Groups
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a paygroup.")]
    [Remote("DoesPaygroupExist", "UpdateFiles", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Paygroup already exists!")]
    public string PayGroup { get; set; }
    public List<UploadFiles> files {get; set;}

}
public class UploadFiles
{
    public string Paygroup { get; set; }
    public string DateAdded { get; set; }


}
```

and your controller function should fill a list of `UploadFiles`

```
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        var fullpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/sourcefiles"), "paygroup.txt");
        List<string> paygroupsList = new List<string>();
        List<string> DateList = new List<string>();
        string line;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fullpath))
        {
            List<UploadFiles> lst = new List<UploadFiles>()
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] strArray = line.Split('|');
                UploadFiles model = new UploadFiles()
                {
                   Paygroups = strArray[0],
                   DateAdded = strArray[1]
                };
                lst.Add(model);
            }
            Groups group = new Groups();
            group.files = lst;
            return View(group);
        }
    }
```

Then in your view, the Model should be

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Groups

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Paygroups</th>
        <th>Date added</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var record in Model.files)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@record.Paygroup </td>
            <td>@record.DateAdded </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
```

Comment: @Xiodrade oh, wait something wrong I notice here in the model, wait I'm editing my answer

Comment: Thanks! That works! I believe I understand what you are saying. An issue that occurs because of converting my model to a list though is that my validation portion of my view no longer works. `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PayGroup, new { @class = "control-label" })` with the error message `'List<UploadFiles>' does not contain a definition for 'PayGroup' and no extension method 'PayGroup' accepting a first argument of type 'List<UploadFiles>' could be found`
Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: This is happening because it's looking for List<UploadFiles> due to the change in model, but it can't find PayGroup in that list. Not sure how to fix it

Comment: You would rather separate the PayGroup in a separate model. let me edit this answer to demonestrate this

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what Groups does so I understand what you did and understand how to use it in the future. Also - Your answer gives me a couple of errors. The first being `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'WebApplication2.Models.Groups' because 'WebApplication2.Models.Groups' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'` because List was removed from the model. The second being `'Group' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`

Comment: Did you mean to do `Groups group = new Groups();`? If so that makes more sense. It still leaves the `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'WebApplication2.Models.Groups' because 'WebApplication2.Models.Groups' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'` error though because List was taken off the model in the view

Comment: Forgot to update this, but wow. I actually didn't realize you added Files in there as the list name, so once I changed `var record in Model` to `var record in Model.Files` it worked.